# Code Coverage data generation Failed

Tags: ios, xcode

When i run my test project with slather i got this log
anyone has ideas to fix it?

> 2015-12-14 14:39:29.483 xctest[7880:987585] The bundle
>   “Famima_StampTests.xctest” couldn’t be loaded. Try reinstalling the
>   bundle. 2015-12-14 14:39:29.484 xctest[7880:987585]
>   (dlopen(/Users/wx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Famima_Stamp-akiykixzlljhyegfebcgflamfzgb/Build/Intermediates/CodeCoverage/Famima_Stamp/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Famima_StampTests.xctest/Famima_StampTests,
>   265): Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_AgreementViewController
>   Referenced from:
>   /Users/wx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Famima_Stamp-akiykixzlljhyegfebcgflamfzgb/Build/Intermediates/CodeCoverage/Famima_Stamp/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Famima_StampTests.xctest/Famima_StampTests
>   Expected in:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Agents/xctest
>   in
>   /Users/wx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Famima_Stamp-akiykixzlljhyegfebcgflamfzgb/Build/Intermediates/CodeCoverage/Famima_Stamp/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Famima_StampTests.xctest/Famima_StampTests)
>   Program ended with exit code: 83

Comment: Do you have a question ?

Comment: yes i cant run my test target success

Comment: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_AgreementViewController <--- is this class added to your Tests ?

Comment: i‘m sure it has been add added 
i always got this error when i run my test target

Answer (score -2):

I solved this problem, just like I solve most of those XCode Problems:

1. delete your projects files in your `DerivedData` (`Xcode>Preferences>Locations>DerivedData→` to jump there in finder)
2. `Product>Clean`
3. (keep alt-Button pressed) `Product>Clean Build Folder`
4. Quit XCode
5. Restart XCode
6. Remove your app from your device / simulator

Try again. 
In case it still doesn't work, use another simulator / device for a few runs. Sooner or later it will work again on the original one again.